# Searching for empty string in str.indexOf() in javascript

Tags: javascript

Searching for the empty string using `String.indexOf(searchValue[,fromindex])` returns unexpected results as given in the following snippet.

```js
console.log('foo'.indexOf('')) // 0
console.log('foo'.indexOf('',2)) // 2
console.log('foo'.indexOf('',3)) // 3
console.log('foo'.indexOf('',4)) // 3
console.log('foo'.indexOf('',100)) // 3
```

Comment: Why unexpected?

Comment: works perfectly fine

Comment: 'Searching for an empty string' sounds like 'division by zero' to me. The results are going to be similar. Empty string is contained anywhere and everywhere in the string. So the indexOf method might like to return arbitrary numbers. ;-) Search only if the 'needle' string complies with if (!needle.isEmpty()).

Comment: I suppose you are looking for `if (!foo || foo.trim() == "")` - sure sounds like an X/Y problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It searches for the first match, starting at the position given with the second argument (the `fromIndex` - if any). But the empty string will *always* be matched as soon as possible; it's an empty string, after all. When you provide a `fromIndex` greater than the length of the string, it simply runs the test as if the `fromIndex` was the length of the string:

> An integer representing the index at which to start the search; the default value is 0. For fromIndex values lower than 0 or greater than str.length, the search starts at index 0 and str.length respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Empty string exist everywhere, for example for your first log, the empty string exist in first of string, you can think of "foo" as "" + "foo", same as other logs. basically indexOf returns the index of the first occurrence of the character in the character sequence represented by this object, or -1 if the character does not occur.